# What is the equivalent of a C# drop down combo box on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing an application using Objective-C for iPhone.

In this application, the user, while entering a new record, needs to have a lookup capability (such as state, gender, phone type, etc).  In C# i usually use a drop down combo or something like that to accomplish this task.  What is the equivalent in Objective-C? Can someone show me a sample application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at UIPickerView. It uses a spinning wheel to show a set of values that can be selected by the user. You need to create an object that adopts the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol to handle responding to what the user selects, and an object that adopts UIPickerViewDataSource protocol to populate the picker view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

[image: UIPickerView Image]

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerView is pretty much the same thing as a dropdown combo box, except without the dropdown part

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent would be a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

If you want to choose a date then use [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDatePicker).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use UIActionSheet. Works quite well as combo box.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

there is an iOS combobox api that might help you add a combobox component to your app. Check it here: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/365/ZComboBox/